# Custom button with gradient outline and icon with transparent background

Tags: android, android-layout, button, gradient, android-styles

I am trying to create custom buttons for my android application. These buttons are simply to add/edit/delete data on the screen. However, I would like to do some nice styling to the buttons but I am having some difficulties with the way android programming works.

The idea is to have a border of a given thickness (let's say 2dp) whose color is a gradient. This implies the center being transparent however and I consider this to be one of the main difficulties. Along with this, I would like the inside of the button to have an icon representing its function.

Currently, I have the gradient and its rounded edges like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="top">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:centerColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:endColor="@android:color/white"
                android:angle="270" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This corresponds to what I want color-wise. However, having a transparent center seems impossible to do in a drawable resource file.

Along with this issue, in my code, I have a `ListView` above a `LinearLayout` containing three buttons which this styling should eventually be applied to. However, I am unable to even change the background color of the buttons.

Here is the code representing the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddPlayersActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_players_activity_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/add_players_activity_title"
        android:id="@+id/add_players_activity_current_players"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
        android:text="@string/current_players"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/add_players_activity_player_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/add_players_activity_current_players"
        android:layout_above="@id/add_players_activity_button_layout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_players_activity_button_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:text="Add"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:text="Edit"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:text="Delete" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

None of the other StackOverflow questions have solved either of my issues. Even the most common "Set the `style` attribute of the buttons" one.

I'm very open to solutions that could require external tools or other things so don't feel limited to internal functions. I do however feel that there has to be a way around this within the Android Studio.

Thanks in advance to anyone that takes time to look into this!

Here is an example as requested (Only difference is I will be using a drawable/image instead of text)

[image: Example]

Comment: if you don't mind, could you add an example of what exactly you want, an image example will be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend creating a custom view for this. Creating a custom view would be highly beneficial to you as have mentioned you have many buttons. With a custom view, you can reuse your button with varying height, width, border width, colors, and corner radius.

Read more custom views [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components). You could also go through a series of codelabs starting [this one](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-andoid-kotlin-training-custom-views/#0).

**attrs.xml** (values/attrs.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Custom attributes for the button -->
    <declare-styleable name="StyledButton">
        <attr name="cornerRadius" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="borderWidth" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="startColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="centerColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="endColor" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**StyledButton.kt**:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.LinearGradient
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.graphics.Shader
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
import androidx.core.content.withStyledAttributes

class StyledButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatImageButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var cornerRadius = 0f
    private var borderWidth = 0f
    private var startColor = 0
    private var centerColor = 0
    private var endColor = 0

    private val path = Path()
    private val borderPaint = Paint().apply {
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }

    init {
        //Get the values you set in xml
        context.withStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.StyledButton) {
            borderWidth = getDimension(R.styleable.StyledButton_borderWidth, 10f)
            cornerRadius = getDimension(R.styleable.StyledButton_cornerRadius, 10f)
            startColor = getColor(R.styleable.StyledButton_startColor, Color.WHITE)
            centerColor = getColor(R.styleable.StyledButton_centerColor, Color.RED)
            endColor = getColor(R.styleable.StyledButton_endColor, Color.BLACK)
        }
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        // Create and set your gradient here so that the gradient size is always correct
        borderPaint.shader = LinearGradient(
            0f,
            0f,
            width.toFloat(),
            height.toFloat(),
            intArrayOf(startColor, centerColor, endColor),
            null,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
        )
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        //Remove inner section (that you require to be transparent) from canvas
        path.rewind()
        path.addRoundRect(
            borderWidth,
            borderWidth,
            width.toFloat() - borderWidth,
            height.toFloat() - borderWidth,
            cornerRadius - borderWidth / 2, 
            cornerRadius - borderWidth / 2,
            Path.Direction.CCW
        )
        canvas.clipOutPath(path)

        //Draw gradient on the outer section
        path.rewind()
        path.addRoundRect(
            0f,
            0f,
            width.toFloat(),
            height.toFloat(),
            cornerRadius,
            cornerRadius,
            Path.Direction.CCW
        )
        canvas.drawPath(path, borderPaint)
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```xml
<com.example.andriod.myapplication.StyledButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:borderWidth="2dp"
    app:cornerRadius="20dp"
    app:startColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:centerColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

**Result**

[image: Styled button result]

Comment: I will try this soon. I'll accept the answer if it works (it would be useless to accept without trying). Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the best solution, but You can do it easy in this way:

1. Create `gradient_back.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:startColor="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

2. Create `shape_front.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="9dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

3. Now in Your layout create a button like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_back">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_front"
        android:text="WOW" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

Version with the transparent body but not with gradient:

1. To Your `build.gradle` (Module: app) add:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1"
```

2. in `res/values/styles` change parent style to:

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

3. Now in layout You can add a button:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WOW"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    app:cornerRadius="10dp"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp"
    app:strokeColor="@color/colorAccent" />
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: The issue is that this uses a solid colour fill over the gradient background and I need a transparent center which seems to be really difficult.

Comment: @MaxMichel aah, oh right, that changes things :/ I will try to think about another solution